# How do I subscribe in sequence and return only the value from the last observable in RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, concatmap

I'm in an Angular route resolver and want to return an observable.

I need to subscribe to multiple async processes in order:

A => B(a) => C(b)

C depends on B and B depends on A. A must complete, then B, then C, but I only want the value from C to be used to cause the route to resolve.

I've tried two different approaches:

```js
return A.pipe(
  concatMap(a => 
    B(a).pipe(
      concatMap(b => 
        C(b).pipe((c) => c); // also tried of(c)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I've also tried

```js
return A.pipe(
  concatMap(a => {
    return B(a).pipe(map(b => {a: a, b: b});
  ),
  concatMap({a, b} => {
    return C(b);
  )
);
```

How do I subscribe to A, then B, then C ..., and then only get the value from the innermost observable?

If I put a tap after my last concatMap I get my expected return value. But my resolver never resolves? (or the wrong thing is getting emitted? I cannot really tell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route resolvers need to complete before the Angular Router will continue. This is the same for route guards also. Adding a operator that takes an emission, such as take(1), or first() and completes will solve the problem.

```
return A.pipe(
  concatMap(a => {
    return B(a).pipe(map(b => {a: a, b: b});
  ),
  concatMap({a, b} => {
    return C(b);
  ),
  take(1)
);
```

Comment: It works, but why is it that when it is a single observable I don't have to use any operators like take?

Answer (score 2):

If one of the observables in the chain never completes (like route params or query params), it'll halt the whole train.

`switchMap` should do:

```
A.pipe(
    switchMap(B), // which is more or less the same as `switchMap(a => B(a))`
    switchMap(C),
).subscribe(//...
```

Comment: B needs the value from A and C needs the value from B. Won't switchMap stop the outer when the inner emits?

Comment: B gets A's output and C gets B's output. You can try whether it works, or write some more detail about the streams involved.

Comment: I did not try your answer because I got an answer from another source that said to simply use a take(1) which did exactly what I needed. Somewhere, and your answer is correct in this at the very least, one of my observables was not completing.